# what does 0 link means in bash file descriptor?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, process, kernel

Each process uses a set of open files in linux . Now bash ( a shell ) is also a process which uses different file descriptor for standard input output.
If I find some file descriptors :

```
ls -l /proc/$$/fd  

lrwx------ 1 viky viky 64 Jan 15 16:29 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 viky viky 64 Jan 15 16:29 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 viky viky 64 Jan 15 16:29 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 viky viky 64 Jan 15 16:30 255 -> /dev/pts/0
```

Now , the 0,1,2,255 are file descriptors . Now , if we see here 0,1,2 is pointing to my current terminal ( taking input from terminal and showing output and error to terminal ).
The question is , what is the role of stdin ( /dev/stdin ), stdout ( /dev/stdout ) and stderr ( /dev/stderr ) . 0,1,2 are default standard streams for stdin , stdout and stderr .

How standard streams are related to the ouput of above command ?

lets say , file descriptor for /dev/stdin is 0 . So is /dev/stdin link to /dev/pts/0 for the bash process. ?

can anyone explain in detail pls .

Comment: I guess you have already answered in your question what is the role of these descriptors - these are stdin, stdout and stderr. Could you please clarify what exactly is your question?

Comment: lets say , file descriptor for /dev/stdin is 0 . So is   /dev/stdin link to /dev/pts/0 for the bash process. ?

Comment: As you can see by `ls` command, `/dev/stdin` is a link to `/proc/self/fd/0` (at least in case of Debian). And `/proc/self/fd/0` is a link to `/dev/pts/0`. So `/dev/stdin` is not directly a link to `/dev/pts/0`. It is a link to the descriptor, and the descriptor is a link to `/dev/pts/0`.

Comment: Detailed answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400849/echo-or-print-dev-stdin-dev-stdout-dev-stderr.